# C++ Функции выводит ошибку Id returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, массивы

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int func_input(int);

int main()
{
    const int MAX=10;
    int task_arr[MAX];
    func_input(task_arr[MAX]);
}

int func_input(int op_arr[],int size)
{
    for(int i=0;i<=size;++i)
    {
        cout<<i<<") ";
        cin>>op_arr[i];
        cout<<""<<endl;
    }
}
```

Выводит ошибку

> Id returned 1 exit status

Comment: У вас же не передается размер массива, `func_input(task_arr[MAX],MAX);`

Comment: @LighFusion, да у него вообще код не компилируется...

Comment: @qwertiy - в вашем ответе лучше представить функцию не как int А как void раз это обработчик и нечего не нужно будет возвращать.

Comment: @LighFusion, поправил. Я её правил до тех пор пока не скомпилировалось и этот момент не заметил. Кстати, а чего это ideone решил промолчать на такую ошибку? Вроде VS ругался...

Comment: Хм.. Кто тут ставит плюсы за подсовывание **некомпилируемого** кода под видом работающего? о_О

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Если исправить ошибки компиляции и ошибку с циклом, то всё работает хорошо.

http://ideone.com/t2nTj3

Вообще, проблема может быть связана со строкой

```
for(int i=0;i<=size;++i)
```

в которой происходит выход за границу массива.

Либо с тем, что компилятор сомнительный и не умеет сам делать

```
return 0;
```

в main.

Comment: Всем спасибо, добавил параметры к инициализации функции, как посоветовал оратор сверху.  void func_input(int op_arr[], int size);